# Is it possible that typeof a class equal to an interface?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible that an interface which describes a class equals to the typeof that class?

```
class Point{
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number){}
}

interface IPoint<T> {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    prototype: T;
    new(x: number, y: number): T;
}

export type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false


type R = Equal<typeof Point, IPoint<Point>>; // false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgFwN4Cho+seyEqATgK7CrzEAUADqQEYiLDQAeAXNMqQLYMBTYgBpo9Ji2gBPLj35CAlOgC+mVZhSohAMzDAB0AJIJNAHgAqAPmhZc7WX0HEA3Nlwzujoa7u1i8SlQpWgEucx9cZAEAd2pOT3kRaQdEhTDXdQE2WipUaCCQ6ABRAEdSMBBTAA1RAE1rAF43agtLagVoButzaCytZAATGCroAH5oAEZoLgAmDr6BQYhm1vbO7t62fqHoWrHJ6eg5-ZJSAy5dEAgBTFuCgwAlTuKyitN7+G04JDRRYx-UKYTGhLJZnNAAPQQ6CXa63TBAA)

As far as I know, `IPoint<Point>` has the same structure as `class Point`.
But they are not equal. Did I miss something?

UPDATE：

My understanding:
When interface describing a function signature or constructor, it is describing a `function` object. `class` is fundamentally functions, so properties of a `function` is just static properties of that `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `x` and `y` properties from `IPoint<T>` interface because they are represent static properties.

Class `Point` does not have static properties.
Try:

```js
type Check = keyof typeof Point // "prototype"
```

As you see, there is only `prototype`.

You should move `x` and `y` to return type of  `new(x: number, y: number): { x: number, y: number };`

Return type of `new()...` represents instance type of class

Consider full example:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }
}

interface IPoint<T> {
  prototype: T;
  new(x: number, y: number): { x: number, y: number };
}

export type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false


type Check = keyof typeof Point // "prototype"
type R = Equal<typeof Point, IPoint<Point>>; // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgF2gbwFDWseyEqATgK7CrzEAUADqQEYiLDQAeAXNMqQLYMBTYgBpo9Ji2gBPLj35CAlJmgBfLGqwpUQgGZhgA6AEkEWgDwAVAHyYcY4vEqoptAVwsBuO8gEB3apzcfIIi0rLBilwY7OHyoTJBcapeGgJstFTozq7QAKIAjqRgIGYAGqIAmjYAvHbUllbUStU2FtBp2sgAJjCl0AD80ACM0FwATEodAt0QdQ1N0C3QbVMz0BUDw6PQE5skpIZceiAQAljn2YYAwgAWAsAA1ovQDwJS8DrQlx9wSGjQAHoAdAAES0BxOFwCEFYS7QABKzwKRRK30%20pjQohMf1QZgxqCsVg8gOB%20zO5yAA)

**UPDATE**
If you want to declare static properties, do it in this way:

```js
class Point {
  static x: number;
  static y: number;
  constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }
}

interface IPoint<T> {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  prototype: T;
  new(x: number, y: number): { x: number, y: number };
}

export type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false


type Result = Equal<typeof Point, IPoint<Point>>; // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgF2gbwFDWhVYqiw0AHgFzTICuAtgEYCmATgNw54FEkCelNDFu1zB4yfM2rBU8ZgAoADtXohiZfnSbMANNCUq1fKppYBKTNAC%20Wa1hSoWAMzDBG0AJIJ7AHgAqAPkwOCmNBNg4jAS1hPWZ4GVQeBUZKXxjkRgB3ORColl1Ik2ZTSgx1UK0CjTCrdltGUgVZdETk6ABRAEdqMBBvAA1dAE1AgF4OOT9-OXNRwN9oBodkABMYfugAfmgARmhKACZzJcZViAmpmeg56AWTs%20ghrd396CPn1Ek3SmcQCEYsIDWm4AEqMCDUEDoUYdbq9bzA%20COOBINC6Tyo1DeLxofz%20VjQAD0hOgn2oAMBQA)